# how to run Queue Jobs Manually Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

i'm new to laravel. here i'm create jobs on manually like

```
$date = 1615603320
PushNotification::dispatch()->delay($date);
```

Now i'm checking on database Its Showing on `3231207358`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSInI.png)

But its not working on particular Time ?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: thanks For connect @ChinLeung Check Question once

Comment: Did you start your queue worker?

Comment: Yes, its Available Time Show Different @ChinLeung

Comment: The time in database doesn't mean your queue worker has started. What is your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `.env` set to?

Comment: my QUEUE_CONNECTION in env is database @ChinLeung

Comment: Did you run `php artisan queue:work`?

Comment: The delay parameter is the number of seconds or a date of when to run the job. How long do you want your delay?

Comment: That DateTime Is Dynamically Added From Database @ChinLeung

Comment: I mean it's normal that the available_at is later, you are adding lots of seconds to the delay. You can try `delay(1)`. It's simply adding the parameter you passing to the current itme.

Comment: i know but i need too run on specific time Thank you

Comment: You can simply pass an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` if you want to have it at the specified date. `delay(Carbon::parse($date));`